# Flash CSS colour between previous colour and new colour

Tags: html, css, less

Suppose I have a `div` with a colour added with `background-color:red or green`. I want to make this flash another colour, where the 'non-flash' is the previous colour value.

```
HTML
<div class='red make-green flash'></div>

LESS
.red{
  background-color:red;
  .make-green{
    background-color:green;
  }
}
.flash{
   animation: flash 2s infinite;
}
@keyframes flash {
 0%{
    background-color:blue;
 }
 50%{
    background-color:            ;<-- what goes here?
 }
 100%{
    background-color:blue;
 }
}
```

If we remove `.make-green` the `div` should flash `red | blue`, with the `make-green` it would flash `green | blue`.

Comment: The common color is blue so that should be the base background color I'd suggest.

Comment: I can see that works in this specific case; what if it is more generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use css variables, if you are okay with the [non-perfect browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=css%20variables).

```css
:root {
  --bg: red;
}

.red {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: var(--bg);
}

.make-green {
  --bg: green;
}

.flash {
  animation: color 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes color {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: var(--bg);
  }
  100% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='red make-green flash'></div>
<div class='red flash'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea without CSS variables where you can slightly change the animation to consider the initial state of the element. Without specifying the `100%` state the browser will automatically consider the value specified inside the element.

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.make-green {
  background-color: green;
}


.flash {
  animation: flashE 1s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes flashE {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='red flash'>Some text</div>

<div class='red make-green flash'>Some text</div>
```